# Troubles with Java and HTTPS

Tags: java, ssl, nginx

I've got a server and domain [nodeserver.fvds.ru](https://nodeserver.fvds.ru/) with "lets encrypt" https configured on it. Nginx redirects all the requests to local java program that listens to some port. My browser can send request. Also I can send requests using Chrome plugin called Advanced REST Client. But if I try to send get request using Java like this:

```
public static String getResponse(String urlToRead) throws Exception {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        URL url = new URL(urlToRead);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
        String line;
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            result.append(line);
        }
        rd.close();
        return result.toString();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        System.out.println(getResponse("https://nodeserver.fvds.ru/"));
    }
```

I will get

> Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:
>   sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:
>   sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
>   find valid certification path to requested target

Answer (score 0):

Is your server certificate self-signed? If that's the case, Java will not be able to find a certification path from your server certificate to any of its trusted CAs.

If that's just for testing pusposes, you could add your self-signed server certificate to your java client truststore (by default, JRE_PATH/lib/security/cacerts).

If that's your production environment, you should avoid the usage of self-signed certificates

Comment: Sorry @Tony, I didn't know what letsencrypt is. Do you know if that certificate is trusted by your server java version? It looks like it is not to me... (https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/will-the-cross-root-cover-trust-by-the-default-list-in-the-jdk-jre/134).

Comment: If that server is not trusted for your java version, then adding it to your truststore should solve your problem